# Use Default Table Name & Custom Schema w/ EF Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Working with EF Code First, I'd like to specify a schema (`Data`) for tables, but let EF use its default convention to name the tables.

I'm using `DataAnnotations.Schema` `TableAnnotations` to set schema.

```
[Table("Customers", Schema = "Data")]
public class Customer
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

But this requires me to set `Name` manually while I want EF to use its convention to name the tables.

I tried to set the `Name` with an empty string.

```
[Table("", Schema = "Data")]
```

That throws the following - very reasonable, expected - error:

> The argument 'name' cannot be null, empty or contain only white space.

Is there any way to let EF default to its table name convention while specifying the schema?

Comment: `modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("Data");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done as `Table` attribute has only one constructor, which requires `Name` to be specified.

Please refer to [MSDN - TableAttribute Constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.tableattribute.tableattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public TableAttribute(
string name
)
```

Answer (score 1):

[Slava Utesinov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5630778/slava-utesinov) suggested using `modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("Data");` to set the default schma.

This will work when there is only one schema that one wishes to set; however will not work when there is more than one schema to apply, without having to set the Table Name manually.

```
public class ExampleContext: DbContext
{
    public ExampleContext() : base("ExampleContext") { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("Data");
        ///...
    }
```